# How to split and count number of occurences of word in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

everyone.

I have a file with names in a format :

```
Name Name    Surname Surname
```

This is the file with Names

```
Nikola  KAZIKOVA
Pavel   MILAN GAZDIK
Nikolas Martin  STRUP
Nikola  GAZDIK
Nikola ČERNÁ
Nikola Martina ČERNÁ
```

I am trying to create a script that prints a number of occurences next to each name.
However I can't figure out how to count them.

This is my code, I can load the text into an array but I can't figure out how to count the names.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

if [[ -z $1 ]]
    then echo "ERROR: FILE NOT FOUND"
    exit
fi


# Read the file in parameter and fill the array named "array"
getArray() {
    array=() # Create array
    while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
    do
        array+=("$line") # Append line to the array
    done < "$1"
}

# Print the file (print each element of the array)
getArray $file
for e in "${array[@]}"
do
    IFS='   ' read -ra arr <<< "$e"
    echo "${arr[0]}" | grep -o "${arr[0]}"

done
```

This is the result I am trying to achieve

```
   [4] Nikola  KAZIKOVA
   [1] Pavel   MILAN GAZDIK
   [1] Nikolas Martin  STRUP
   [4] Nikola  GAZDIK
   [4] Nikola ČERNÁ
   [4] Nikola Martina ČERNÁ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:

```
while read -r f l ; do echo "[$(grep -w -c $f d.dat)] $f $l" ; done <d.dat
```

Output:

```
[4] Nikola KAZIKOVA
[1] Pavel MILAN GAZDIK
[1] Nikolas Martin  STRUP
[4] Nikola GAZDIK
[4] Nikola ČERNÁ
[4] Nikola Martina ČERNÁ
```

Note, this is not terribly efficient due to the `grep` inside a loop.  If your file is large, then you may want to utilize alternate tools like. `awk` or `python`.

---

`awk` alternative;

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]++}NR>FNR{for(i in A) {if(i==$1){printf "[%s] %s\n", A[i], $0}}}' d.dat d.dat
```

Output:

```
[4] Nikola  KAZIKOVA
[1] Pavel   MILAN GAZDIK
[1] Nikolas Martin  STRUP
[4] Nikola  GAZDIK
[4] Nikola ČERNÁ
[4] Nikola Martina ČERNÁ
```

Answer (score 2):

with your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk '
{
  value[FNR]=$0
  occur[$1]++
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){
    split(value[i],arr,FS)
    print "["occur[arr[1]] "] " value[i]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```bash
awk '                                       ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  value[FNR]=$0                             ##Creating array named value which has index as current line number and value as currnet line value.
  occur[$1]++                               ##Creating array named occur with index of 1st field and keep adding same index element here.
}
END{                                        ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){                      ##Using for loop till value of FNR here.
    split(value[i],arr,FS)                  ##Splitting value[i] into arr with separator as space.
    print "["occur[arr[1]] "] " value[i]    ##Printing values as per requirement here.
  }
}
'  Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed, sort, uniq):

```
sed 's/ .*//' file |
sort |
uniq -c | 
sed -nE 's/^\s*(\S+) (\S+)/s#^\2\\b#[\1] \&#/p' |
sed -f - file
```

Remove all but the first name from each line.

Sort the names.

Using `uniq` count the number of occurrences of each name.

Turn the above result into a sed script which prefixes each name with its count in `[n]` format.

Apply the above sed script to the original file.

Answer (score 1):

If the input/data is not too large/big, a pure bash solution would be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A Name
declare -a full_name names

while read -ra names; do
  full_name+=("${names[*]}")
  ((Name[${names[0]}]++))
done < file.txt

for name in "${!full_name[@]}"; do
  first_name="${full_name[$name]%% *}"
  for key in "${!Name[@]}"; do
    [[ "$first_name" == "$key" ]] &&
    printf '[%d] %s\n' "${Name[$key]}" "${full_name[$name]}" &&
    break
  done
done
```